# Android, CRUD with realm and image in base64

Tags: android

I do not find how to do in android a CRUD with Realm DB that stores images in base64, help, and try many ways

Answer (score 0):

your problem look like just let images Bitmap convert to base64String then use realm's CRUD can do it successfully.

```
    public static String BitmapToBase64String(Bitmap bitmap) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
            byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    String encode= Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);
    encode = encode.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");        
    return encode;
}
```

save this Base64String in your realm db.
I hope it will be helpful to you.